# How to display different columns from 2 tables with a subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have 2 tables, which are related on a shared column `customer_id`:

- `customer`
- `rental`

I need to display the `rental_id` and `last_update` from the `rental` table.
Also the `active` column from the `customer` table where `active` is false

I have searched multiple websites, as well as several questions here on Stack Overflow and this is the closest I have gotten:

```
SELECT rental_id, last_update, active
FROM rental
WHERE customer_id IN
    (SELECT customer_id
     FROM customer
     WHERE active = false);
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

*Edit:* I have to use a subquery as this is a school project so inner join answers do not help. Sorry.

Comment: If `active` is always false, why do you need to get it from the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the subquery only returns customers where `active = false`, there's no need to get that column from the table, you can just hard-code it into the `SELECT` list.

```
SELECT rental_id, last_update, false AS active
FROM rental
WHERE customer_id IN (
    SELECT customer_id
    FROM customer
    WHERE active = false)
```

There's no way to get non-constant data from a table without it being one of the `FROM` or `JOIN` tables.

BTW, in my experience, MySQL is often very poor at optimizing `WHERE c in (SELECT ...)`. I try to avoid them at all costs, and I think your teacher is misguided in prohibiting them.

Comment: That solved it. Thank you. I will remember that method in future.

Answer (score 0):

Try a query like this. It use INNER JOIN instead of subselect

```
SELECT
    r.rental_id,
    r.last_update,
    c.active
FROM rental r
INNER JOIN 
    customer c ON c.cusomer_id = r.customer_id
WHERE
    c.active = FALSE;
```

Comment: Unfortunately as I am doing a school assignment I have to use a subquery. If I use an inner join I lose marks. Thanks anyways though.

Comment: It's not possible to do this without a join.

Comment: You can als direct output **FALSE as active** the subselect will give you only customer_id **where active = FALSE**